# How to use nltk sentence tokenizer in case of bulleted-data or listed data?

Tags: python, nlp, nltk

I am using nltk sentence tokenizer to fetch sentences of files.
But it fails terribly when there are bullets/listed data.

[Example text](http://pastebin.com/6YA1JNzb)

Code I am using is:

```
dataFile = open(inputFile, 'r')
fileContent = dataFile.read()
fileContent = re.sub("\n+", " ", fileContent)
sentences = nltk.sent_tokenize(fileContent)
print(sentences)
```

I want the sentence tokenizer to give each bullet as a sentence.

Can someone please help me here? Thanks!

**Edit1**:
Raw ppt sample: http://pastebin.com/dbwKCESg
Processed ppt data: http://pastebin.com/0N64krKC

I will recieve only the processed data file and need to sentence tokenize on the same.

Comment: Can you post a link to a sample file instead of typing them onto the question? That will help us know how to split the data.

Comment: Please edit your question to show the minimal code needed to replicate your error http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: what do you mean when you say "fails terribly"? Does the program fail or is the output just not what you want?

Comment: By fails I mean that it doesn't consider each bullet as a new sentence. Like in the sample, each bullet should be output as an individual sentence but instead they get merged among other sentences.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question is a bit unclear but I tried your code and it seems to fail when trying to parse the bullets. I've added a function to strip non-printable characters and added a find/replace to replace newlines with periods. Printable strings on my python version are:

```
0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ!"#$%&\'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\\]^_`{|}~ \t\n\r\x0b\x0c
```

This code creates sentences out of your bullets, while still separating sentences out of the blocks of text. It would fail if sentences in the input text had newlines in the middle of them - which your example input does not.

```
import re, nltk, string

dataFile = open(inputFile, 'r')
fileContent = dataFile.read()
fileContent = re.sub("\n+", ".", fileContent)
fileContentAscii = ''.join(filter(lambda x:x in string.printable,fileContent))
sentences = nltk.sent_tokenize(fileContentAscii)
```

Comment: Bullet characters is not the problem. The tokenizer doesn't recognise that each bullet point is a individual sentence esp cos in most documents, each bullet may not end with a period. Any way to handle that?

Comment: doesnt using substituting newlines with periods like I do fix that? Since bullets end in new lines.

Comment: Aah, i guess that would work. Will have to try. But the sent tokenizer isn't working on fileContentAscii; i'm getting an 'Expected string/buffer' error.

Comment: I replaced `fileContentAscii = filter(lambda x: x in string.printable, fileContent)` with `fileContentAscii = ''.join(filter(lambda x:x in string.printable, fileContent))` and it worked.

Comment: Btw this works if the bullet is an extra special character. What is the bullets are just hypens or a character which in the the string.printable list? Any ideas? just thinking ahead.

Comment: Wouldn't it still work because it still ends with a newline?

Comment: Oh wait! just realised! Actually if the content of a ppt with bullets is transferred to a text file or compressed into one, then this will actually not work as the newline may not be detected.

Comment: why wouldnt the newline be detected?

Comment: It might be scraped off as an initial cleanup of the ppt files.

Comment: hmm yeah you'll probably have to use some regex to select what you want to replace with periods to define sentences